# The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed

Tags: java, html, парсер

Кормлю HTML org.w3c.dom.Document-у (вот html в [оригинальной](http://pastebin.com/WK3xUqer) и [удобночитаемой](http://pastebin.com/XVMxxFvS) форме):

```
org.w3c.dom.Document doc = (org.w3c.dom.Document) builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(result.getBytes("utf-8")));  //See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706493/java-net-malformedurlexception-no-protocol , if don't know why ByteArrayInputStream
```

Вылетает:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 98; The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
```

98 символ это "h" в `<h1 style="margin-bottom:20px">`

Что делать?

P.S. HTML таскаю от [сюда](http://ntvplus.ru/tv/schedule.xl?genre=all&channel=3356&date=7.9.2013&date=8.9.2013&date=10.9.2013&date=11.9.2013&date=12.9.2013&date=13.9.2013&date=14.9.2013&date=15.9.2013&time=day), мне надо его как-то распарсить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[валидатором](http://validator.w3.org/) пройдитесь по этому документу. он не валидный, парсер валится совершенно справедливо. попытайтесь сделать его валидным, добавив html, body, остальное поправить, например глобальной заменой, если надо...